# Add a column or Join tables?

Tags: sql-server

I have the following table:

**Material** table (to be built)

```
MaterialID
ProductID
ProductDescription
OtherPropetries...
```

**Products** table (already exists)

```
ProductID
ProductDescription
```

In the `Material` table, should I leave `ProductDescription`, or remove it and join the `Material` and `Product` tables through the `ProductCode` column? And which one is better performance wise?

I recognize the redundancy of adding the `Description` column but wondering if a performance gain - *if any* - is worth it.

Comment: Your preference. I doubt a description field is really going to impact performance. Unless of course it's a nvarchar(MAX) with millions of entries and each entry has GBs worth of text. Then you would have a problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a redundant field to a table improves the performance for reading, BUT slows down, when writing (inserting or updating), uses more disk space and may lead to more complex code (for inserting).

So, it depends on your uses cases. If doing fast queries is very important for your application you can do this.

However, theres a proverb saying: Make it run, make it right, make it fast. So you probably should postpone such a performance optimisation till the point, when you find, that you really need it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have indexes in place, your system would have to scale *very* large for performance to be a consideration.

I would avoid duplicating data.  Managing duplicate data is a nightmare.  What happens when you correct the description of a product code?  Do you populate it through both tables?  If you happen to code something that imports and updates the Product table, are you always going to remember to update the Material table, and vice-versa?  Or are you going to allow the Material table to have a different description?  Are your users going to understand why that will happen when a Product and a Material disagree on the Product description of the exact same Product Code?  Is there ever a use case for that to happen?  What happens if your users decided they want to interact with the database using a third party application?  Will *that* application remember to update both locations, or do you have to put in a trigger or something to synchronize them somehow?  If you don't do that, will your users be able to tell which description was the most recently used one?

My other question is:  I'm assuming ProductCode must be unique since you're using it as the foreign key in Material in your sample design.  If that's the case... why does Product have a ProductID field?  If you're not actually using the surrogate key (which is what I'm assuming ProductID is) then what purpose does ProductID serve?